# Carousel with dynamic content

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I came across a carousel from Twitter bootstrap here. http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel

It looks really good. But all the images / content in the example are hard-coded. How can I request the server for new content and show it in the carousel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer would have to be adjusted for each language, but assuming you're programing in PHP, it may look something like this:

If you have an array of images:

```
$images = ['path/to/image.jpg', 'path/to/image2.jpg', 'path/to/image3.jpg']
```

Then you'd loop through those images, and place each one in the appropriate HTML markup, like so:

```
<?php foreach ($images as $image) { ?>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="<?php echo $image ?>" />
  </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: @Hendrik I hard-coded the `$images` array simply for the sake of showing what it held. In practice, that array would be generated from your database, making it dynamic.

Comment: See this example for ajax on slide http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961719/twitter-bootstrap-dynamic-carousel