# twitter bootstrap dynamic carousel

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'd like to use bootstrap's carousel to dynamically scroll through content (for example, search results). So, I don't know how many pages of content there will be, and I don't want to fetch a subsequent page unless the user clicks on the next button.

I looked at this question: [Carousel with dynamic content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232618/carousel-with-dynamic-content), but I don't think the answer applies because it appears to suggest loading all content (images in that case) from a DB server side and returns everything as static content.

My best guess is to intercept the click event on the button press, make the ajax call for the next page of search results, dynamically update the page when the ajax call returns, then generate a slide event for the carousel. But none of this is really discussed or documented on the bootstrap pages. Any ideas welcome.

Answer (score 16):

If you (or anyone else) is still looking for a solution on this, I will share the solution I discovered for loading content via AJAX into the Bootstrap Carousel..

The solution turned out to be a little tricky since there is no way to easily determine the current slide of the carousel. With some data attributes I was able to handle the `.slid` event (as you suggested) and then load content from another url using jQuery `$.load()`..

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
  interval:false // remove interval for manual sliding
});

// when the carousel slides, load the ajax content
$('#myCarousel').on('slid', function (e) {

    // get index of currently active item
    var idx = $('#myCarousel .item.active').index();
    var url = $('.item.active').data('url');

    // ajax load from data-url
    $('.item').html("wait...");
    $('.item').load(url,function(result){
        $('#myCarousel').carousel(idx);  
    });

});

// load first slide
$('[data-slide-number=0]').load($('[data-slide-number=0]').data('url'),function(result){    
    $('#myCarousel').carousel(0);
});
```

<kbd>[**Demo on Bootply**](http://bootply.com/62742)</kbd>

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this solution still requires to initially load all the slides albeit empty?

Answer (score 0):

I combined @Zim's answer with Bootstrap 4. I hope it will help someone.

First, load just the path of the images:

```html
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item" data-url="/image/1.png"></div>
        <div class="carousel-item" data-url="/image/2.png"></div>
        <div class="carousel-item" data-url="/image/3.png"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in JavaScript:

```js
$('document').ready(function () {
    const loadCarouselImage = function ($el) {
        let url = $el.data('url');
    
        $el.html(function () {
            let $img = $('<img />', {
                'src': url
            });
            $img.addClass('d-block w-100');
                    
            return $img;
        });
    );

    const init = function () {
        let $firstCarousel = $('#carousel .carousel-item:first');
        loadCarouselImage($firstCarousel);
        $firstCarousel.addClass('active');

        $('#productsCarousel').carousel({
            interval: 5000
        });
     };

     $('#carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
         loadCarouselImage($('#carousel .carousel-item.active'));
     });

     init();
});
```