# How to fadein fadeout images which file names are coming from a database and get always repopulated?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery array in which are file names of jpg-images are stored.

I split them to a javascript array.

Each record in my database table have different image file names. I am able to update this javascript array whenever I skip the record to next or previous.

How can I, with a button click open a slideshow which use always the current array data (for example "test.jpg", "test2.jpg" and so on)?

I checked a lot in stackoverflow but found no answer.

I have no idea how to start.

the bxslider that was here mentioned, is exact the problem that I have.

Here is the code that makes me problems:

```
            <ul class="bxslider">
              <li><img src="/images/pic1.jpg" /></li>
              <li><img src="/images/pic2.jpg" /></li>
              <li><img src="/images/pic3.jpg" /></li>
              <li><img src="/images/pic4.jpg" /></li>
            </ul>
```

I can not use this code to fill the slideshow, because I need to refill this images always with new values depending which record in the database it is.

Example: My textfield in the database have "file01.jpg ; file02.jpg ; file03.jpg".

Another record have "fruits01.jpg ; fruits02.jpg"

How can I replace this ... img src="/images/pic1.jpg" ... in run time with my values?

I would prefer that the slideshow read the values from a Javascript array.

Comment: What do you mean by jquery array .. can you pls post some code ?

Comment: I guess you need a jQuery library to display the photos right? Actually a lot of free jQuery library available over the web, check this out: http://bxslider.com/

Comment: This article provides a tutorial for doing a slideshow that gets its images via an array: http://www.devcurry.com/2010/03/simple-image-slideshow-using-jquery.html

Comment: Take a look here for a Bootstrap Carousel with AJAX data: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961719/twitter-bootstrap-dynamic-carousel