# Issue with active class bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue with the bootstrap carousel and the needed "active" class. Now I load images via ajax and before I just used the += operator to "add" the new content with the old content but that wont work anymore. I was wondering if bootstrap has a method or settings to dynamically add the "active" class before looking for it. Any suggestions?

Comment: please post some code.

Comment: There is no code. There is a general question requesting a general answer. If theres setting to add active class.

Comment: Related: I think this is the solution you're looking for - [Add slides to Bootstrap 3 carousal dynamically using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24177572/add-slides-to-bootstrap3-carousal-dynamically-using-jquery) and [twitter bootstrap dynamic carousel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961719/twitter-bootstrap-dynamic-carousel).